# Which odata format required to build smart table in sapui5?

Tags: sapui5

We want to use OData without Annotations to build a smart table.
I am trying to build smart table and I have an OData service where which is giving me a project list. But Annotations are not present in my response.

Please suggest the exact way to do this.

Comment: please share your code, the error you are getting, and how you created your service, that way it is easier to help you without asking a 100 times for you to share diffrent things...

Answer (score 1):

The annotations don't need to come in the OData service metadata.
You can add them to a separate local file in your application.

In your `manifest.json` file, define an annotation file and associate it to your data source:

```
        "mainService": {
            "uri": "/path/to/ODATA_SERVICE/",
            "type": "OData",
            "settings": {
                "odataVersion": "2.0",
                "annotations": [
                    "my-local-annotations"
                ]
            }
        },
        "my-local-annotations": {
            "uri": "annotation/my-annotations-file.xml",
            "type": "ODataAnnotation",
            "settings": {
                "localUri": "annotation/my-annotations-file.xml"
            }
        }
```

In your annotation XML file, you can add the annotations you need.

For SmartTable specifically I'd suggest you take a look at `com.sap.vocabularies.UI.v1.SelectionFields` and `com.sap.vocabularies.UI.v1.LineItem`.

References:

Annotation samples and schemas in the OpenUI5 repository:
https://github.com/SAP/openui5/tree/master/src/sap.ui.core/test/sap/ui/core/demokit/sample/ViewTemplate/scenario/data